# Android App with XML web service

Tags: android, database, web-services, security, soap

We are planning to develop an android application with web service integration using SOAP . There are some authentication details(user id ,password etc.), which are needed to access the web-service . Is it secure to put this details in application's local database? If you have any alternate options, please share with us.

Comment: use database encryption or use sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to save passwords locally, it's not safe to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use userid to store in local database.
But i think you don't need to save password in your local database.

So, my suggestion is, if necessary store userid not password or another option is use "preference" for this type of storage.